# Source could be corrupt or not supported

Tags: r, spatial, r-sf

I am looking to create a map using this dataset:
[data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YAG_S16YgP1U9KTLfhIPSCXrOV3LW2Hc/view?usp=sharing)

With the shape file of [shapefile](https://geoportal.statistics.gov.uk/datasets/ons::local-authority-districts-december-2018-boundaries-uk-bfe/explore?location=54.317948%2C-3.250000%2C6.72)

Here is the following R code:

```r
library("tidyverse")
library("dplyr")
library("sf")
library("ggplot2")
library("tmap")
library("tmaptools")
library("RColorBrewer")


data = readr::read_csv("C:/Users/amanm/Desktop/annualincomedata.csv")


localauthorities2 <- read_sf("C:/Users/amanm/Desktop/localauthorities2.shp")

map_and_data <- merge(localauthorities,data)

str(map_and_data)

ggplot(map_and_data) = 
  geom_sf(oes(fill = Percentage), color = NA) +
  scale_filla_viridis_c()
```

I am given a error whilst trying to run the code:

```r
> localauthorities2 <- read_sf("C:/Users/amanm/Desktop/localauthorities2.shp")
Error: Cannot open "C:\Users\amanm\Desktop\localauthorities2.shp"; The source could be corrupt or not supported. See `st_drivers()` for a list of supported formats.
In addition: Warning message:
In CPL_read_ogr(dsn, layer, query, as.character(options), quiet,  :
  GDAL Error 4: Unable to open C:\Users\amanm\Desktop\localauthorities2.shx or C:\Users\amanm\Desktop\localauthorities2.SHX. Set SHAPE_RESTORE_SHX config option to YES to restore or create it.
```

Any advice would be useful.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A shapefile consists of a bunch of files with different extensions - .shp, .dbf and .shx being the most essential. It looks like you've not got the corresponding .shx file:

```
  GDAL Error 4: Unable to open C:\Users\amanm\Desktop\localauthorities2.shx or C:\Users\amanm\Desktop\localauthorities2.SHX. Set SHAPE_RESTORE_SHX config option to YES to restore or create it.
```

You can set config options in GDAL as environment variables. I made a shapefile called `foo` with all its components and deleted the .shx. Reading it produces the error:

```
> st_read("foo.shp")
Error: Cannot open "foo.shp"; The source could be corrupt or not supported. See `st_drivers()` for a list of supported formats.
In addition: Warning message:
In CPL_read_ogr(dsn, layer, query, as.character(options), quiet,  :
  GDAL Error 4: Unable to open foo.shx or foo.SHX. Set SHAPE_RESTORE_SHX config option to YES to restore or create it.
```

setting the option in the environment fixes it:

```
> Sys.setenv(SHAPE_RESTORE_SHX="YES")
> st_read("foo.shp")
Reading layer `foo' from data source `foo.shp' using driver `ESRI Shapefile'
Simple feature collection with 10 features and 1 field
Geometry type: POINT
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: 1 ymin: 1 xmax: 10 ymax: 10
CRS:           NA
```

However if you've not got the corresponding `.dbf` file nothing is going to regenerate that from scratch since it contains the attributes. Chances are you'll find that in the same place as the `.shx` and then you don't need this hack.